# How do I edit the implementation's file of texdate package?

Tags: packages, babel

I'm trying to use texdate package in portuguese language. I've read the documentation and I'm sure about what to do. However I can not find the appropriated file to edit. I think it was a file named like texdate.sty, but it does not exist.
Help me please.....
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to instead use the `datetime2` package which has built-in support for Portuguese with support for `babel`.

The documentation is at https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf

---

If, however, you really want to use `texdate` instead, you'll need to define a number of macros to override the existing language support since Portuguese is not one of the languages handled out of the box with `texdate`. The documentation for `texdate` gives the set of commands that are necessary for German which you can modify for Portuguese:

```
\makeatletter 
\def\texd@firstmon{Januar} 
\def\texd@firstshmon{Jan} 
\def\texd@secondmon{Februar} 
\def\texd@secondshmon{Feb} 
\def\texd@thirdmon{M ̈arz} 
\def\texd@thirdshmon{M ̈arz} 
\def\texd@fourthmon{April} 
\def\texd@fourthshmon{Apr} 
\def\texd@fifthmon{Mai} 
\def\texd@fifthshmon{Mai} 
\def\texd@sixthmon{Juni} 
\def\texd@sixthshmon{Juni} 
\def\texd@seventhmon{Juli} 
\def\texd@seventhshmon{Juli} 
\def\texd@eighthmon{August} 
\def\texd@eighthshmon{Aug} 
\def\texd@ninthmon{September} 
\def\texd@ninthshmon{Sept} 
\def\texd@tenthmon{Oktober} 
\def\texd@tenthshmon{Okt} 
\def\texd@eleventhmon{November} 
\def\texd@eleventhshmon{Nov} 
\def\texd@twelfthmon{Dezember} 
\def\texd@twelfthshmon{Dez} 
\def\texd@firstdayname{Sonntag} 
\def\texd@firstdayshname{So} 
\def\texd@seconddayname{Montag} 
\def\texd@seconddayshname{Mo} 
\def\texd@thirddayname{Dienstag} 
\def\texd@thirddayshname{Di} 
\def\texd@fourthdayname{Mittwoch} 
\def\texd@fourthdayshname{Mi} 
\def\texd@fifthdayname{Donnerstag} 
\def\texd@fifthdayshname{Do} 
\def\texd@sixthdayname{Freitag}
\def\texd@sixthdayshname{Fr} 
\def\texd@seventhdayname{Samstag} 
\def\texd@seventhdayshname{Sa} 
\makeatother
```

Just put these definitions after `\usepackage{texdate}` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did it. Run´s perfectly! Thanks!!!